# escaping "\" in the end of a string in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to create a string that ends with `"\"`. For example:

```
set str {",$"23"^#@$\'"\}
```

This won't work because tcl thinks that I'm escaping the `"}"` here.
So I tried to escape the `"\"`

```
set str {",$"23"^#@$\'"\\}
```

but now the value of str is `",$"23"^#@$\'"\\`. 
I want the value of str to be with one `"\"` in the end: `",$"23"^#@$\'"\`

How can I do that while creating the string inside `{}`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could think is to use *format*:

```
puts [format {",$"23"^#@$\'"%s} \\]
",$"23"^#@$\'"\
```

I think you could even try with the *%c* and the ascii code of the *\*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; this is one of the small number of cases that can't be quoted that way. Here's the proof from an interactive session:

```
% gets stdin s
",$"23"^#@$\'"\
15
% list $s
\",\$\"23\"^#@\$\\'\"\\
```

Other such cases are thing like where there's unbalanced braces, and so on. They really don't come up very often. That backslash form above generated by `list` is the alternative (and you can put it in double quotes if you wish).